# Comparing multiple very large csv files against each other

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have n csv files which I need to compare against each other and modify them afterwards.
The Problem is that each csv file has around 800.000 lines.

To read the csv file I use *fgetcsv* and it works good. Get some memory pikes but in the end it is fast enough. But if I try to compare the array against each other it takes ages.

One other Problem is that I have to use a foreach to get the csv data with fgetcsv because of the n amount of files. I end up with one ultra big array and can't compare it with array_diff. So i need to compare it with nested foreach loops and that take ages.

a code snippet for better understanding:

```
foreach( $files as $value ) {
    $data[] = $csv->read( $value['path'] );
}
```

my csv class use fgetcsv to add the output to the array:

```
fgetcsv( $this->_fh, $this->_lengthToRead, $this->_delimiter, $this->_enclosure )
```

Every data of all the csv files are stored in the $data array. This is probably the first big mistake to use only one array, but I have no clue how to stay flexible with the files without to use an foreach. I tried to use flexible variable names but I stucked there as well :)

Now I have this big array. Normally if I try to compare the values against each other and to find out if the data from file one exists in file two and so on, I use array_diff or array_intersect. But in this case I have only this one big array. And as I said, to run an foreach over it takes ages.

Also after only 3 files I have an array with 3 * 800.000 entries. I guess latest after 10 files my memory will explode.

So is there any better way to use PHP to compare n amount of very large csv files?

Comment: Does it have to be PHP? Maybe there is a command-line utility that does this? How are you comparing the files exactly?

Comment: I am a programmer of the 1980' - then we solved it by using sort, then some logic to compare, then a third file with result. Some times you spilt the job in smaller chunks - and then run them serial.
This is not a solution, but a way of thinking ...

Comment: what's the point in storing all files in one array?

Comment: I need to compare them against each other and generate a new array out of it which I modify and send it over an API. So in the end, I need it back to PHP for the API. @Col. as I said the point is I don't have a clue how to split it and stay flexible :)

Comment: you have no clue how to split? but your data already splitted! into separate files! Why can't you read them into separate arrays? or even read into array only first and then check others by reading one by one line?

Comment: Must the data be in CSV format?  Why not import it into a database?  Most DBMSes support importing CSV files into tables without too much difficulty, and once it's in there you can run queries against the data to get your comparison.

Comment: @the data is splitted thats right, but the amount is flexible. So I have to use a foreach to read the csv for each file. So I have to call  fgetcsv or whatever during the loop. How should I get back the data to different arrays. As I said I tried it with onward counting variable names but I stucked there and tried to find out if there is  an better / easier approach. Reading one by one line is not possible because the data in each file is mixed up. Thanks

Comment: @GordonM the csv comes out of the api and there is no other way to get the data. I can set up DB and put each csv into the DB but I don't want to use a DB only to put the files temporary in if I don't need to. In the end if there is no better approach I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: What data do you want to return exactly? the diff between to csv's? the intersect? What will the return be when there's 3 or more source-csv's involved? Can they be processed sequentially?

Comment: thanks for the help, i use the sql solution now. Not the best but works fine :) @ontrack the intersect between 1 and n and vise versa. But never mind I use a database now. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use SQL**

- Create a table with the same columns as your CSV files.
- Insert the data from the first CSV file.
- Add indexes to speed up queries.
- Compare with other CSV files by reading a line and issuing a SELECT.

You did not describe how you compare n files, and there are several ways to do so. If you just want to find the line that are in A1 but not in A2,...,An, then you'll just have to add a boolean column *diff* in your table. If you want to know in which files a line is repeated, you'll need a text column, or a new table if a line can be in several files.

*Edit:* a few words on performance if you're using MySQL (I do not now much about other RDBMS).

Inserting lines one by one would be too slow. You probably can't use `LOAD DATA` unless you can put the CSV files directly onto the DB server's filesystem. So I guess the best solution is to read a few hundreds of lines in the CSV then send a multiple insert query `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (..1..), (..2..)`.

You can't issue a `SELECT` for each line you read in your other files, so you'd better put them in another table. Then issue a multiple-table update to mark the rows that are identical in the tables t1 and t2: `UPDATE t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b) SET t1.diff=1`

Maybe you could try using sqlite. No concurrency problems here, and it could be faster than the client/server model of MySQL. And you don't need to setup much to use sqlite.

Comment: Thanks. I need to compare if A1 is in file 2/3/4 on any position and so on. I guess I will give it a try with a temporary database

Comment: Yeah I use LOAD DATA to import the csv. Its still slow but its ok for now. Thanks dude.